# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в данном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

В данном предложении:

Когда думаешь, сходить ли в кафе с друзьями?

Comment: об чём речь в предложении?

Answer (score 1):

Возможны **варианты:**

(1) *Когда **думаешь** (= собираешься, предполагаешь) **сходить** в кафе с друзьями?*

Составное глагольное сказуемое "***думаешь сходить***". вспомогательный глагол ***думаешь*** здесь имеет **модальное** значение возможности, необходимости, волеизъявления и т.п.: мочь, хотеть, решить и др.

**[Словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42):** думать, пункт 3. **с инф.** Намереваться, собираться. Думает выехать завтра. Думал было заняться живописью. Я и не думаю смеяться! Чайник и не думает кипеть. Не думай выходить без пальто (не смей).

(2) *Когда, **думаешь,** (мне, нам) сходить в кафе с друзьями?*

В значении **вводного слова**.

**Примечание.**  Вопросительная частица **ЛИ** к этой теме не подходит, так как есть вопросительное местоимение ***когда.***

Без местоимения "когда":  ***Как** думаешь, **не сходить ли** в кафе с друзьями.*